# How to convert linked notes in a word document to footnotes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros

There is a hyperlink leading to part of a text in a document, but I need to convert this linked note text to a footnote. How can I do this?

I tried [this macro](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/convert_reference_notes_to_dynamic_footnotes.html), but didn't had any success because it can't just find plain digits with spaces or tabs, it needs to have square brackets for it to work properly. So I was thinking of a way to add square brackets in numbers in text and find and replace note numbers with 'Note #:', but I can't find tab spaces for some reason and style for these specific hyperlinks is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It already looks like it is a footnote. I take it that this is not the case.

1. Select the text of the note. Cut it.
2. Delete the number (8) and hyperlink.
3. Where you want the note in your text to the footnote, use Insert
   Footnote.
4. Paste your footnote text.

To do anything like this with macros would require access to a sample file with multiple notes created the way they are in your problem document. *Otherwise, anyone offering suggestions for macro language is shooting in the dark.*

How many of these are there? It may be simplest to do this manually.